# angular 5 make picture fit on mat-toolbar with matmenu

Tags: angular, image, resize, angular-material, toolbar

Not that familiar with css or perhaps tools I could use to make this work, what is the best way to make an image fit in the toolbar such that:

1) the matmenu button appears in the right hand corner on top of the picture not next to the picture.
2) the picture resizes from a wide screen to a mobile screen size properly.

could I use Grid for this? Or different @Media settings?

```html
<mat-toolbar class="toolbarClass">
  <button mat-button disabled>
    <img class="jpg-icon"  src="../../../../assets/img/owls.jpg" 
        style="max-width:    100%; min-width: 100%;">
  </button>
  <button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="appMenu"><mat-icon>menu</mat-icon> Menu</button>
    
     <mat-menu #appMenu="matMenu">
         <button mat-menu-item *ngIf="(loggedIn)" [routerLink="['./login']">
         Login</button>
         <button mat-menu-item *ngIf="(loggedIn)" [routerLink] 
         ="['./register']">Register</button>
        <button mat-menu-item *ngIf="(loggedIn)" [routerLink]="['./logout']"> 
          Logout         </button>
        <button mat-menu-item *ngIf="(loggedIn)" [routerLink]="['./profile']"> 
        Profile </button>
        <button mat-menu-item *ngIf="(loggedIn)" [routerLink]="['./main']"> Main </button>
        </mat-menu>


</mat-toolbar>
```

[image]

Comment: Try to declare the picture as the background of your mat-toolbar and play with background-size css attribute to see which one is doing the trick.

Comment: should I use width in px or % in order to get the resizing to smaller device correct?

Comment: try this mat-toolbar{ background:url('path/to/your/pic'); background-size:cover}

Comment: @oudekaas, by the way you don't need the ../.././../ in the assets just type "assets/img/owls.jpg"